# How to bound and make unique ticket values in Lamport's Bakery Algorithm? Mutex, C++

Tags: c++, mutex, mutual-exclusion

community. I have searched for a while, but haven't found any optimizations for **Lamport's bakery algorithm** that ensures unique ticket values for each thread and bounds these values within some range.

In other words, there exists a **Black-White bakery algorithm** which *bounds* the ticket values, but how can it be optimized to ensure them being *unique*?
Or I can write the solution with an atomic variable(fetch_add operation) and hereby make ticket values unique, but then how this variable can be bounded or in which cases it should be dropped??

Below is the code which gives unique tickets for each thread. Please, help me to bound this _ticket_counter by applying some decrease operations or give any idea, link for a suitable algorithm.

```
extern const int NUM_THREADS;

class ImprovedBakeryLock : public Lockable {
public:
    ImprovedBakeryLock();
    ~ImprovedBakeryLock();
    void lock(int i) override;
    bool try_lock(int i) override;
    void unlock(int i) override;
private:
    std::atomic<uint64_t> _ticket_counter;
    volatile uint64_t* _token;
    const int _n;
};
ImprovedBakeryLock::ImprovedBakeryLock() :
    _n(NUM_THREADS), _ticket_counter(1)
{
    _token = new uint64_t[_n];
    memset((void*)_token, 0, _n * sizeof(uint64_t));
}
void ImprovedBakeryLock::lock(int num)
{
    _token[num] = _ticket_counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);

    for (int j = 0; j < _n; ++j) {
        while (_token[j] != 0 && _token[j] < _token[num])
            std::this_thread::yield();
    }
}
bool ImprovedBakeryLock::try_lock(int num)
{
    _token[num] = _ticket_counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    bool acquired = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < _n && acquired; ++j) {
        if (_token[j] != 0 && _token[j] < _token[num]) {
            acquired = false;
            _token[num] = 0;
        }
    }
    return acquired;
}
void ImprovedBakeryLock::unlock(int num)
{
    _token[num] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the interest of the bakery algorithm the fact that it works without atomic operations?

Comment: Yeah, to some extent, I agree with you. But the restriction for my task is a ticket uniqueness and I'm just wondering whether it's possible also to bound tickets. But I don't quite understand what is the point of making them unique. Is it more optimal?